# Material Select blinking on iOS

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, materialize

I am trying to create my website in Material Design, however I found one issue with Material Select regardless whether I use MDB (Material Design for Bootstrap) or Materialize CSS framework. Both are working fine on Windows/OSX/Android , however for some reason when I open [Material Select component](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) on my iPad and click on it, there is a blinking cursor showing from the Background of the Dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
input.select-dropdown {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    -o-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on iOS devices, I am using select dropdown from materialisecss "http://materializecss.com/forms.html".
to fix the blinking cursor issue, I used reference code from below link and slightly modified that code.

Ref Link: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/901 (check comment by "chi-bd commented on 17 Nov 2015")

```
jQuery('select').material_select();
/*--- Materialize Select dropdown blinking cursor fix for iOS devices ---*/
jQuery('select').siblings('input.select-dropdown').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        if (e.clientX >= e.target.clientWidth || e.clientY >= e.target.clientHeight) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

jQuery('select').material_select(); to initialize materialise select and rest code is the fix.

the only problem was this was giving problem on desktop view so added mobile detection condition

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
```

**Note:** Add this code in document ready $(document).ready(function() { ... });

that's it. I hope this will sort out your issue.
Regards, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6514) on github, [@StaticBR](https://github.com/StaticBR) proposed an approach to solve "Dropdown Broken on iPhone (and Safari in general)" issue, link [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/dropdown.js).

According to @StaticBR,

"The Issue is that IO13 Safari propagate TouchEnd Events before the Click event is propagated.

So if you have a click listener within an drop down, it is not correctly triggerd, because the Dropwdown is getting closed by the TouchEnd event. After that the click event is at a different position or does not longer exist.
Removing the touch event listener solved this issue for me."

Answer (score -1):

Apologies, the above code works but then it stops the scrolling for drop-down.

For now I am using below fix, but it shows the blinking cursor first and then it hides it. but still this is not the perfect solution, if anyone has better solution please post here :)

```
function checkDropDown(obj){
var nextObj = jQuery(obj).next();
setTimeout(function(){       
    if (jQuery(nextObj).is(":visible")){
        jQuery("input.select-dropdown").css({
            "transition"    : "none",
            "left"            :    "-999999px"
        });
    }else{
        jQuery("input.select-dropdown").css({
            "left"            :    0
        });
    }
}, 250);
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input.select-dropdown").on("focus", function(){
        checkDropDown(jQuery(this));
    });
    jQuery("input.select-dropdown").on("blur", function(){
        checkDropDown(jQuery(this));
    });
});
```